# How to interface two different fragments from one activity

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have two different layouts, for two different fragments, but in single activity. I am using onAttachFragment callback, but I am unable to use both the interfaces simultaneously.

```
public interface AvInterface{
    public void onMessageRead(String data);
}

public interface WeInterface{
    public void onMessageRead(String data);
}

somefunction(){

avInterface.onMessageRead("14221322345124");
weInterface.onMessageRead("142620405958");

}

public void onAttachFragment(Fragment fragment) {
    super.onAttachFragment(fragment);

    try {
        avaInterface = (AvInterface) fragment;
        weInterface = (WeInterface) fragment;
    }
    catch (ClassCastException e) {
        //throw new ClassCastException(fragment.toString()+" must override AvInterface");
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't need 2 interfaces, as they have 100% same methods. Use one of them

Comment: but method definations are different, and both of them use different layouts

Comment: both methods are `public void onMessageRead(String data);`.

Comment: wil it work if i change name of methods, because both have diffenent functionalities

Comment: then you will need 2 interfaces. The question so far looks like you don't need to change method names and need only 1 interface. Since you didn't mention any more details - that's all so far.

Comment: well  I stated i have different functionalities. Kindly help

Comment: `Since you didn't mention any more details - that's all so far.` It is not possible to `Kindly help` without the details

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `onAttach()` callback in Fragment.

From `onAttachFragment()` [doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment#onAttachFragment) :

```
Called when a fragment is attached as a child of this fragment.
```

This is a callback provided when you attach a child fragment is attached to the current fragment.

I think you are hosting both fragments in the activity and hence use `onAttach()` to get access to the interface to communicate with the activity.

Answer (score 0):

Like mentioned by @Arka Prava Basu, you only need one Interafce and you do something like the following in your parent activity

```
if(fragment InstanceOf fragmentA){
    dosomething();
}else{
    dosomethingelse()
}
```

I hope you get the idea.